# Returning 400 rather than 404 from ASP.NET MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created the hello world of ASP.NET MVC web API projects using VS2012:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Issuing a get request to that controller returns some XML of the data with status 200.  All good so far.

When I remove that method, like this:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    //public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    //{
    //    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    //}

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

I then get a 404 not found.  What I want is a 400 bad request, because an ID must be provided.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you want is wrong.  404 is the correct status code here.

Comment: @SLaks: Agreed, but 400 is the business requirement.  They see it as passing a blank ID, same as passing an alphanum string rather than int string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to keep the `Get()` method just to throw an error.
Change the signature of your Get by ID method to:

```
public string Get(int? id = null)
{
    if (id == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    return "value";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is the answer I went with because of an automated test and documentation harness that we have throwing up "ambiguous method" errors.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to include the method, but throw an exception instead:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public void Get()
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Action Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0#iactionresult-type) types if you don't want to import extra packages for the exceptions.

Instead of throwing an exception you do return a new `BadRequestResult` instance. Mind the return Action type as well that must be declared.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
[Route("/api/yourtype")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        // 400
        return new BadRequestResult();
    }

    public ActionResult<YourType> Get(int id)
    {
        // 404
        return NotFound();

        // 200
        return Ok(object);
    }
}
```